# Web crawler page iteration

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have written this code that goes to webMD and so far extracts all the link from each sub category in the message boards. What I was to do next is to make the program go through all the pages of the subcategory link. I have tried many thing but I always face a problem any idea?

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd


source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://messageboards.webmd.com/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['link'],data=[url.a.get('href') for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link")])
lists=[]
for i in range(0,33):
    link = (df.link.iloc[i])
    source1 = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1,'lxml')
```

Comment: what is the problem that you face? Have you checked out scrapy?

Comment: The problem is when I go to the first page of the sublink, i dont know how to continue with the rest of the pages.

Comment: When you've visited the first sublink page you'll again have to read the source and extract the info you're looking for, be it further links or posts. scrapy.org appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: i though about that but it has to be an easier way. Doing that you need to have many many for loops

Comment: @Data1234 have you resolved this issue now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Python and [Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to do a similar task in the past.  [See Wget documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html). You can look into the source to get an idea of how it works.

Basically you can do the following. See the follwoing Pseudo code

```
alreadyDownloadedUrls = []
currentPageUrls = []

def pageDownloader('url'):
    downaload the given URL
    append the url to 'alreadyDownloadedUrls' list
    return the given URL

def urlFinder('inputPage'): 
    finds and returns all the URL of the input page in a list

def urlFilter ('inputUrl or list of URLs'):
    check if the input list of URLs are already in the 'alreadyDownloadedUrls' list, 
    if not appends that URL to a local list variable and returns

def controlFunction(firstPage):
    Download the first page
    firstPageDownload = pageDownloader(firstPage)
    foundUrls = urlFinder (firstPageDownload)
    validUrls = urlFilter(foundUrls)
    currentlyWorkingList = []
    for ( the length of validUrls):
         downloadUrl = pageDownloader(aUrl from the list)
         append to currentlyWorkingList
    for (the lenght of currentlyWorkingList):
        call controlFunction() recursively
```

However, [recursively](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php) calling  will result you to download the whole internet.
So you have to validate URLs and see if its from the parent domain or subdomain. You can do that in the *urlFilterFunction*.

Also you have to add some more validation to check if you are downloading the same link with a hash tag at the end of the url. Unless your programme will think [this](https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/parenting/2590/is-your-house-baby-proof/3746) and [this](https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/parenting/2590/is-your-house-baby-proof/3746#3746) URLs are pointing to a different pages.

You may also introduce a depth limit as in Wget

Hope this clears the idea to you.